# "Answers to non-wiki questions" on user profile page are actually "non-wiki answers"

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, community-wiki, profile-page

The [tags page of user profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/79365/ju-z79365?tab=tags) displays additional statistics on mouse-over. For example, hovering over number $3$ in `3 linear-algebra × 29` brings up the following:

[image: stats]

This is incorrect: all of my [29 posts in the linear-algebra tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:79365+[linear-algebra]) were answers on non-wiki questions. It's just that 22 of them were marked as CW *answers*.

The words *Answered X non-wiki questions* should be replaced with  *Posted X non-wiki answers*, to align the text with the number it accompanies.

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed that the formulation has been changed:

[image: new situation]

(On main, only the part about answers is in the tooltip.)

In addition to fixing this bug, it now also includes the total score for the non-wiki questions you asked.

If I speculate a bit, this opens up potential for new badges.

Comment: Re: your flag. The status-completed tag is usually applied by developers. I prefer to let them, who are most "in the know", do so. I leave your flag open in hope that a dev will see it.

Comment: @WillieWong Understood. Thanks for the heads up and the explanation.

Comment: Please anybody explain me what is a 'non-wiki answer'?

Comment: @AkshayHegde It is an answer which has not been marked as [community wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)

Comment: @najibidrissi thanks for the comment.